# Comparing two arrays with For loop with python

Tags: arrays, python-2.7

Hello new here in stackoverflow, also I am new with the programation in Python and still learning.

I want to know why I am getting a Syntax error in the second for loop, I am trying to compare two arrays of the same lenght, when ax > bx A recive 1 point, when ax < bx B recive 1 point and where ax == bx nobody get points.

```
def solve(a0, a1, a2, b0, b1, b2):
  A = 0
  B = 0
  a = [a0 , a1 ,a2]
  b = [b0, b1, b2]
  for x in a and for y in b:
    if x > y:
        pointA + 1
    if x==y:
        pass
    else:
        pointB + 1
  result = [pointA, pointB]
  return result


a0, a1, a2 = raw_input().strip().split(' ')
a0, a1, a2 = [int(a0), int(a1), int(a2)]
b0, b1, b2 = raw_input().strip().split(' ')
b0, b1, b2 = [int(b0), int(b1), int(b2)]
result = solve(a0, a1, a2, b0, b1, b2)
print " ".join(map(str, result))
```

then with some Investigation I tried:

```
from itertools import product
import sys


def solve(a0, a1, a2, b0, b1, b2):
  A = 0
  B = 0
  a = [a0 , a1 ,a2]
  b = [b0, b1, b2]
  A = sum(1 if x>y else 0 for x, y in product(a, b))
  B = sum(1 if x<y else 0 for x, y in product(a, b))
  result = [A, B]
  return result

a0, a1, a2 = raw_input().strip().split(' ')
a0, a1, a2 = [int(a0), int(a1), int(a2)]
b0, b1, b2 = raw_input().strip().split(' ')
b0, b1, b2 = [int(b0), int(b1), int(b2)]
result = solve(a0, a1, a2, b0, b1, b2)
print " ".join(map(str, result))
```

but when the Input is:

```
1 1 1
0 0 0
```

I got:

```
9 0
```

Can someone explain what I am doing wrong and why? Thank you in advance.

Regards,
R

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`and` expects boolean values not expressions, so this: `for x in a and for y in b:` will never work.

You could use `zip()`:

```
1 a
2 b
3 c
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> b = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> for x, y in zip(a, b):
...   print('{} {}'.format(x, y))
... 
1 a
2 b
3 c
```

And please correct your indentations.

Comment: I made the corrections in the post  and I used zip and now my code is working really good! 

Thank you :)

Comment: Glad I could help.